# Python socket problems on server side

Tags: java, python, sockets

On the python server i plan to receive parameters from a java client, run them through a neural network and send the result back. The messages will be numpy arrays converted to strings for the communication process.
However i'am not that far yet trying to pass some dummy string from the client just to envoke the server routine and everything is fine when i just send a string back. However when i call mod.predict(arr) INSIDE the loop or do not concatenate the received data to the reply, the server doesn't react. Does anyone have an idea how i could get this done?

Server - Python:

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 7777
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(10)

while True:
   conn, addr = s.accept()  
   data = conn.recv(1024)+"\r\n"

   pred = mod.predict(arr)

   reply = 'Answer..' + pred + data      # +'\r\n'

   if not data: 
      break

   conn.send(reply)

conn.close()
```

Client - Java:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out, true);
ps.println("Hello Python!");

InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

while (buff.ready()) {
    System.out.println(buff.readLine());
}

socket.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Server code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                      socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("localhost", 5000))
sock.listen()

while True:
    try:
        sock.listen()
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print(conn.recv(1024))
        conn.send(b"Hello world from Python")
        conn.close()
    except:
        break

sock.close()
```

This is correct, because cURL says so.

```
➜  ~  curl -v localhost:5000
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:5000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Hello world from Python%
```

Oh, and your client code is wrong as well. You need to create a *streaming* socket, not a datagram socket (which is what you have).

Client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        // This constructor creates a streaming socket
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(null), 5000);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out, true);
        ps.println("Hello Python!");

        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while (buff.ready()) {
            System.out.println(buff.readLine());
        }

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However with above changes i don't have to concatenate the client massage to the reply anymore, but the main part what is the calculation mod.predict(arr) is still not possible inside the while loop.

Comment: @AlexK. why isn’t it possible? Do the calculation, make it a string and send it.

Comment: as soon as i call this function in the loop i somehow can't pass a string reply to the client (or client can't read the reply) even without using the result of this func for the reply. However when i call the func and print the result, it is printed on console, but like i said, no kind of message is delivered to the client. (I run the python-server from console and the java-app from eclipse)

Comment: @AlexK. please update the question with the new code, and what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the server code looks like now. All expressions are calculated and printed correctly in the console when i start the server from commandline and then run the java-client from eclipse. What really is strange is that when i pass some string as reply and it seem to work, it can stop working when i just add some print argument in the while loop like in the code below.

```
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import numpy as np

f=open('C:\\nn.pkl','rb')
mod=pickle.load(f)

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print 'Socket bind complete'
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'
while True:
   try:
       s.listen(10)
       conn, addr = s.accept()  
       data = conn.recv(1024)
       print data
       arr = np.array([1.0, 0.9712, 0.01019, 0.333, 0.01008, 0.5625, 0.75, 0.4, 0.25, 0.6, 0.0])
       pred = np.array_str(mod.predict(arr))
       print pred
       reply = "Answer.." + pred
       conn.send(reply)
       conn.close()
   except:
       break
s.close()
```

Additionaly when i repeatedly run the java client while the server is running, i somtimes get an answer and somtimes not because buff.ready() isn't true on every run.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(null), 5000);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out, true);
        ps.println("Hello Python!");

        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while (buff.ready()) {
            System.out.println(buff.readLine());
        }
}
```